# What is a Boolean Function?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Please explain to me what a Boolean function is, and how do I make an expression.

If the statement states that $f=$"she is out of work" and $s=$"she is spending more", how can I write symbolically that ($a$) "Neither is she out of work nor is she spending more"?

Comment: A Boolean function  is a function of the form $f : \mathcal{B}k \to \mathcal{B}$, where $\mathcal{B} = \{0, 1\}$ is a Boolean domain and $k$ is a non-negative integer (the arity of the function).

Answer (score 2):

Not generally speaking, a Boolean function is a function $f:Domain \rightarrow \{true,false\}$.
If you define $f$ as "She is out of work" and $s$ as "She is spending more" then (a) would be:
$$\lnot f \land \lnot s$$

Answer (score 1):

For a state $x$ describing her, the two Boolean functions can be defined as follows:

$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \textrm{ if x = she is out of work} \\
      0 & \textrm{ if x = she is not out of work} \\
   \end{cases}$

$ s(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \textrm{ if x = she is spending more} \\
      0 & \textrm{ if x = she is not spending more} \\
   \end{cases}$

Thus, in symbolic form, (a) can be written as $f = 0 \land s=0$.